# Understanding static initialization in standard 6.7/4

Tags: c++

From the Standard 6.7/4:

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place.

It's not clear if the zero-initialization's being performed during the program-startup or during the control first executes the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will report a longer snippet. That's your secction

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant
>   initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage
>   duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first
>   entered.

That's the follow up, and I understand that this means it can do both. That's the meaning I give to this section (the continuation of the same paragraph)

> An implementation is permitted to perform early
>   initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread
>   storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is
>   permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread
>   storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2).

All we can do now is wait a native english speaker to confirm/confute my legalese decryption...

Comment: Thank you, now since the rules about initialization the variables in a namespace scope is clear I understood it.